# OpenStream throws IOException in AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

***Context:***
I'm developing an Android weather application in Java for a course. This application uses asynctask in order to get from OpenWeather's API the temperature of a city. The API returns a JSON with weather information through an URL like this:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={key}
```

APPID is a key associated to an account in OpenWeather. Here is a JSON example for *Berlin* city:

```
{"coord":{"lon":13.39,"lat":52.52},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":8.49,"pressure":1035,"humidity":61,"temp_min":8,"temp_max":9},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.7,"deg":120},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1542369000,"sys":{"type":1,"id":4892,"message":0.0027,"country":"DE","sunrise":1542349837,"sunset":1542381079},"id":2950159,"name":"Berlin","cod":200}
```

If the city doesn't exists, the API returns a JSON with error 404. The next one is a JSON example for the nonexistent city *Berlina*.

```
{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}
```

I get the JSON with Asynctask. In doInBackground() method, I call the following line in order to get an inputStream:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
```

Then, I parse the JSON in postOnExecute() and show the temperature information with a Toast.

***My question:***
The code works fine with *Berlin*, but openStream throws IOException for *Berlina*. The URL exists and have JSON data, as I explained. So, what could be the reasons for this Exception? Could it be a connection problem?

***Edit with Logcat***
This is the exception detail:

```
11-27 00:01:34.151 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp D/IOException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlina&units=metric&appid=d32068a850405b593a87d410fcc50a4f
11-27 00:01:34.151 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlina&units=metric&appid=d32068a850405b593a87d410fcc50a4f
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.androidapps.user.weatherapp.MainActivity$GetJSONOpenWeather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:219)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at com.androidapps.user.weatherapp.MainActivity$GetJSONOpenWeather.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:204)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-27 00:01:34.152 3152-3346/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-27 00:01:34.192 3152-3180/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42b9b20: ver 2 0
11-27 00:01:34.227 3152-3152/com.androidapps.user.weatherapp D/JSONObjetc: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: What is the exception?  Your log should show it unless you're swallowing it.

Comment: How can I know what is the exception reason? The getMessage() method of IOException shows only the URL.

Comment: Exception.printStackTrace()

Comment: It throws java.io.FileNotFoundException in the URL, but I understand it. I see in the browser that the JSON with the error exists.

Comment: I read the next paragraph about the exception in the documentation: "It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing". So, the JSON is inaccesible for the app. Why?

Comment: Post the actual exception description and stack trace from your log, that will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I added the exception description in the question.

Comment: It seems that OkHttp or something further down in the network stack is turning a 404 response into a FileNotFoundException.  So I guess you will need to catch that exception and take whatever action is appropriate.